# Cakephp Apphelper not sure why that comes into play

Tags: cakephp

Right now I am trying to create a simple app to view and add notes. All I am really doing is just copy bits of code that I'll need from the Post/User the cookbook tutorial at (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

At the "add" page, it tells me that the "NoteHelper" is missing, so I just created a blank "NoteHelper.php" class under View/Helper.

1. Even though this wasn't needed for the "User" tutorial when I when through it, why would I need it this time?
2. Now I am getting this error not sure where to move next, let me know what you thing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create your MVC for Notes, is using Console/bake.
On your 'Add page" double check on the forms, it should look like

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('Notes'); ?>
    <fieldset>
       <legend><?php echo __('Add Notes'); ?></legend>
       <?php 
          echo $this->Form->input('note_title');
          echo $this->Form->textarea('note_description');
       ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

The error happened, because you using $this->Notes->input( '' );

Comment: Yes, that does make sense, must be Friday.